# Command Line like Django Command in Play Framework

Tags: command-line, playframework

I want to make a Java function in Play Framework Project, and want to execute it in terminal like Django command, my purpose is to run it in cron after ready.

Is it possible to do that? I'm sorry, maybe it rather sound silly, but I'm not a java developer, I'm python/Django developer and requested to help another team. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As play strongly supports RESTful approaches to development, you should simply be able to call your Play action via a well defined URL, and then use CURL to call your action via that URL.

However, you could also use the concept of Jobs in Play. Play jobs was designed to give CRON like functionality within your applications without needing to rely on external scheduling mechanisms.

Comment: I found your explanation in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jobs. It's very help. Thank you very much.